# Make a matrix of different list entries in r

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of different matrices like this one:

```
m1 = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = T)  
m2 = matrix(11:14, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
m3 = matrix(101:104, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
m4 = matrix(1001:1004, ncol = 2, byrow = T)

L = list(m1,m2,m3,m4)
```

I would now like to make a bigger matrix like this one:

```
r1 = cbind(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]], L[[4]])
r2 = cbind(L[[2]], L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]])
r3 = cbind(L[[3]], L[[2]], L[[1]], L[[2]])
r4 = cbind(L[[4]], L[[3]], L[[2]], L[[1]])
Final = rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4)  
Final
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2   11   12  101  102 1001 1002
[2,]    3    4   13   14  103  104 1003 1004
[3,]   11   12    1    2   11   12  101  102
[4,]   13   14    3    4   13   14  103  104
[5,]  101  102   11   12    1    2   11   12
[6,]  103  104   13   14    3    4   13   14
[7,] 1001 1002  101  102   11   12    1    2
[8,] 1003 1004  103  104   13   14    3    4
```

As I sometimes have more than 10 entries in the list I would really be happy if there's an easier way than to note every entry down. I found the `do.call("cbind", L)`but this only helps for the first 2 rows. Is there another way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
index <- seq_along(L)
do.call(rbind, lapply(index, function(i) do.call(cbind, L[abs(i-index)+1])))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2   11   12  101  102 1001 1002
#[2,]    3    4   13   14  103  104 1003 1004
#[3,]   11   12    1    2   11   12  101  102
#[4,]   13   14    3    4   13   14  103  104
#[5,]  101  102   11   12    1    2   11   12
#[6,]  103  104   13   14    3    4   13   14
#[7,] 1001 1002  101  102   11   12    1    2
#[8,] 1003 1004  103  104   13   14    3    4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap another `do.call` or `Reduce` and produce the desired result, like this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(1:4, c(2,1,2,3), c(3,2,1,2), c(4:1)),
                     function(i) Reduce(cbind, L[i])))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2   11   12  101  102 1001 1002
[2,]    3    4   13   14  103  104 1003 1004
[3,]   11   12    1    2   11   12  101  102
[4,]   13   14    3    4   13   14  103  104
[5,]  101  102   11   12    1    2   11   12
[6,]  103  104   13   14    3    4   13   14
[7,] 1001 1002  101  102   11   12    1    2
[8,] 1003 1004  103  104   13   14    3    4
```

However, that still leaves the need to manually type in the list `list(1:4, c(2,1,2,3), c(3,2,1,2), c(4:1))`. Considering this as a matrix, we have

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    1    2    3
[3,]    3    2    1    2
[4,]    4    3    2    1
```

which is symmetric. It can be produced using `outer` as follows:

```
abs(outer(1:4, 1:4, "-")) + 1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    1    2    3
[3,]    3    2    1    2
[4,]    4    3    2    1
```

Then put into a list like

```
myList <- split(abs(outer(1:4, 1:4, "-")) + 1, gl(4, 4, 4^2))
```

which can be fed to `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(1:length(L), function(i)
     L[c(i:1,(i+1):length(L))[1:length(L)]]), function(a)
         do.call(cbind, a)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2   11   12  101  102 1001 1002
#[2,]    3    4   13   14  103  104 1003 1004
#[3,]   11   12    1    2  101  102 1001 1002
#[4,]   13   14    3    4  103  104 1003 1004
#[5,]  101  102   11   12    1    2 1001 1002
#[6,]  103  104   13   14    3    4 1003 1004
#[7,] 1001 1002  101  102   11   12    1    2
#[8,] 1003 1004  103  104   13   14    3    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting alternative is:

```
ind = kronecker(toeplitz(cumsum(c(1L, lengths(L)[-length(L)]))), 
                array(0:(length(L[[1]]) - 1), dim(L[[1]])), 
                "+")
array(unlist(L)[ind], dim(ind))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2   11   12  101  102 1001 1002
#[2,]    3    4   13   14  103  104 1003 1004
#[3,]   11   12    1    2   11   12  101  102
#[4,]   13   14    3    4   13   14  103  104
#[5,]  101  102   11   12    1    2   11   12
#[6,]  103  104   13   14    3    4   13   14
#[7,] 1001 1002  101  102   11   12    1    2
#[8,] 1003 1004  103  104   13   14    3    4
```